# Finding the probability that the motorist must stop at only one traffic light, at least two traffic lights

Tags: probability

There are three traffic lights that a motorist must pass on the way to work. The probability that the motorist has to stop at the first traffic light is 0.2, and that for the second and third traffic lights are 0.5 and 0.8 respectively. Find the probability that the motorist has to stop at :

i) **Only one** traffic light

ii) **At least two** traffic lights

Comment: Part (i) has been covered already. For part (ii); note that "at least two" is the same as 1-("stops at zero traffic lights"+"stops at one traffic light").

Comment: P (At least 2 traffic lights) = 1 - ( 0 - 1.5) ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For part i)

Lets list all the cases.

The motorist stops at the first traffic light but not at the other two.

The motorists stops at the second traffic light but not at the first and the third one

The motorists stops at the last traffic light but not at the first two.

What is the probability of any of the above happening?

Comment: P (First traffic light) = 0.2/1.5 ... P (Second traffic light) = 0.5/1.5 ... P (3rd) = 0.8/1.5 .... 0.2 + 0.5 + 0.8 = 1.5

Comment: No, that is incorrect. P(First traffic light)=$0.2\times(1-0.5)\times(1-0.8)$ , not $0.2/1.5$

Comment: Okay, Therefore P (Second traffic light) = 0.5 × (1 - 0.2) × (1 - 0.8) and P (Third traffic light) = 0.8 × (1 - 0.2) × (1 - 0.5) ... Therefore P (First Traffic light) = 0.2 , P ( Second traffic light) = 0.08 and P ( Third traffic light) = 0.32 ... Correct?

Comment: Correct except its $0.02$ for the first one, double check that, and then to get the final answer you add them all up.

Comment: So the probability that the motorist has to drop at $only$ $one$ traffic light is 0.02 + 0.08 + 0.32 = $0.42$ ... what about the probability that the motorist has to drop at at least $TWO$ traffic lights?

Comment: It is either he stops at $0,1,2$ or $3$ traffic lights. So the probability that he stops at at least two traffic lights would be $1-P(0$ lights$) - P(1 $ light$)$. You already figured out the probability that he stops at one traffic light, now what is the probability that he stops at no traffic lights?

Comment: The probability that he stops at no traffic lights = 1 - 0.42 = 0.58 ?

Comment: No that is the probability that he stops at no traffic lights, or at $2$ traffic lights or at all traffic lights.

Comment: For him to stop an no traffic lights, he need to not stop at the first one AND not stop at the second one AND not stop at the third one

Comment: Okay, The probability that he stops at no traffic lights = 0.58 - 0.42 = 0.16 ?

Comment: In general, roughly speaking and in probability means multiply, or means add, when you list out how the situation can happen, so from my previous message the probability that he stops at no traffic lights is $(1-0.2)(1-0.5)(1-0.8)$

Comment: The probability that he stops at no traffic light is 0.08 .... Therefore, the probability that he stops at least TWO stop lights = 1 - P(0 lights) - P(1 light) = 1 - 0.08 - 0.42 = 0.5

Comment: That is correct